# Inserting PDF as byte array to SQL Server stored procedure using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a PDF which I need to insert into a SQL Server table's `varbinary` column.

I convert the PDF into a byte array using C#

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

I add a parameter to the `SqlCommand`:

```
 SqlParameter fileP = new SqlParameter("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
 fileP.Value = bytes;
 myCommand.Parameters.Add(fileP);
```

The stored procedure basically takes a `varbinary` parameter and inserts into a table's `varbinary` column

```
 create procedure pdfInsert 
      @file varbinary(MAX)
 as
     insert ...
```

I get an error on execution of this procedure.

In the SQL Server profiler I found that the following procedure executes

```
exec pdfInsert @file = 0x2555... <-- byte array of pdf
```

The error is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near '40E3'.

In SSMS, when I execute this procedure with single quotes at both of the byte array.

Like this:

```
 exec pdfInsert @file = '0x2555.......'
```

I get the error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Just curious to know what wrong am I doing? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the data type in the table varChar(max) and not varbinary(MAX)?

Comment: @Decker97 Its varbinary(MAX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\pdf.pdf");
    SqlParameter fileP = new SqlParameter("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    fileP.Value = bytes;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(fileP);
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=CoastAppsDev\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=CSharpWinForms;Integrated Security=True;");
    conn.Open();
    myCommand.Connection = conn;
    myCommand.CommandText = "spPdfInsert";
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

with the stored proc:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[spPdfInsert] (
    @file varbinary(max) = null
)
AS


Insert Into Pdfs
(   pdfData )
Values
(   @file )
```

What version of SQL Server are you on?  2008?

Comment: Thanks @Decker97. I had the same piece of code. Found that the new line character in the byte array (which SSMS) puts creates the error. Entire bytearray should be in 1 line and the procedure executes correctly. Thanks for you help anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use Instead of "SqlParameter fileP = new SqlParameter("@file", SqlDbType.VarBinary);"

Use this cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", bytes);

also make sure that column type is varbinary(max) and not any-other data type